# Bat file prints multiple statements

Tags: batch-file

I am invoking bat command in C++.
The command below writes to console "connecting to bootrom: connected . writing 0x001A13".
system("D:\abc\abc.exe -u load D:\abc\13oct\agi\agit")

but when i execute same command to dump the above string into file like this:

system("D:\abc\abc.exe -u load D:\abc\13oct\agi\agit">>D:\abc\13oct\tempFile.txt");

It appears that the temp file is having multiple instances of connected . writing 0x001A13 in tempFile.txt

Does any body point me an appropriate fix for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What bat command? I see no batch file being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I hope I understood this well: The same output you get **once** if the first command appears **twice** in the temp file.

That's probably because you're using `>>` for redirection, which doesn't replace the ouput file, but **appends** to it.

That means, if you execute `echo Test >> tempfile.txt` twice, it will have **two** lines reading *Test*.

If you want to save only the ouput of the last command to the file, use `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: No not like that. Executing D:\abc\abc.exe -u load D:\abc\13oct\agi\agit and "D:\abc\abc.exe -u load D:\abc\13oct\agi\agit">>D:\abc\13oct\tempFile.txt" should yield same output since both are executing same exe that abc.exe. In the second case, it gives 100s of instances of "writing 0x001A13" on in the notepad tempFile.txt

Comment: Did you try `"D:\abc\abc.exe -u load D:\abc\13oct\agi\agit">D:\abc\13oct\tempFile.txt"`? Because each time you run the command with two `>`s, one extra line is added...